# Recursively replacing values in an object

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

Say I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID(1234),
  name: 'Corvid',
  friends: [{
    name: 'Magpie',
    friends: [{
      name: 'Raven'
    }, {
      name: 'Jackdaw',
      friends: [{
        name: Friends.ALL_FRIENDS
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Jay'
  }]
}
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is, for every entry in list of friends, replace the current object with the result of `Friends.findOne({ name: obj.name })`.

I am easy able to iterate through the structure like so.

```
function populate(obj=friends) {
  if (obj.friends) {
    return populate(obj.friends);
  }
  return friends.findOne({ name: obj.name });
}
```

However, what I am having trouble with is *replacing* that object at that specific area. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: I think you could use map to achieve what you want to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: please add some example how and what to replace with some new structure. as i looks, it is - with missing methods - not clear what you like to do.